# How to post data with cURL?

Tags: php, curl

I want to return the response as url instead boolean. I looks header from browser and match it but it only return boolean (1). Is there some options missing?

```
 <?php

    $ch = curl_init();

    $url = 'http://www.tusfiles.net/anfossy50rrd';

// Post field and value
    $post = array(
            'op' => 'download2',
            'id' => 'anfossy50rrd',        
        'rand' => 'q56tfpiklusrizipkforyjqsykxzqlsi7ur3hyi',
            'referer' => '',    
        'method_free' => '',
            'method_premium' => '',
        'down_script' => '1'
        );
```

its the header

```
   $headers = [
        'Host: www.tusfiles.net',
        'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0',
        'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5',
        'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate',
        'Cache-Control: no-cache',
        'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',
        'Referer: http://www.tusfiles.net/anfossy50rrd',
        'Cookie: lang=english; login=lynxpravoka; xfss=; aff=2513158; __atuvc=17%7C36; 

    __atuvs=57cf088127fd55f9004; cookiescriptaccept=visit',
        'Connection: keep-alive',
        'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1'
    ];

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); 

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post);

    $server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

    print_r($server_output);

    ?>
```

Comment: in either case, CURLOPT_VERBOSE should tell you why it's giving no output

Comment: oh i found your problem (using CURLOPT_VERBOSE and trying the code myself); the server returns a `HTTP/1.1 302 Found` redirect response. and you do not have `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` , so curl doesn't follow it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use something like this:

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'X-Header-1: value1',
    'X-Header-2: value2'
    ));`

Or you can also build an array where the key is the header name and the value is of course the header value. It would look something like this:

`$headers = array(
    'Host' => 'www.tusfiles.net',
    'User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0'
 );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);`

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: its still return boolean 1.

Comment: That means it was successful. If you require the output from the request, you'll need to add `curlsetopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);` and then `var_dump($server_output);` to see the result.

Comment: its only return D:\UwAmp\www\index.php:42:string '' (length=0). i want it generate the link.

Comment: the field rand will random every 1 hour. i already check it. but its till return boolean 1

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that the server returns a `HTTP/1.1 302 Found` HTTP redirect, expecting you to send the request to the "found" URL. but because you do not have CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION - nor do you manually handle redirects (nor read the redirect headers at all), you do not follow the redirect. enable `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` , and you should get the response.

also,  you should practically never give the 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate', header manually with curl. if curl was not actually compiled with gzip or deflate and the server decides to use it, the transfer will fail, furthermore, if, in the future, both the server and curl supports an even better transfer encoding, it won't be used because you explicitly said only gzip/deflate was supported. instead, make curl give all supported encodings automatically, by giving an empty string '' to CURLOPT_ENCODING.

and a protip: in the future, to debug why curl transfers isn't working as expected, enable CURLOPT_VERBOSE